# Express.JS - Dynamic Route Alias

Tags: regex, node.js, express, replace

I am designing a community site that will allow users to login and befriend others, and their account will be accessible via the following routes:

```
https://domain.com/en/community/id/:userid AND
https://domain.com/en/community/users/:username
```

However I want to always want users to use the first URL as it looks more aesthetically pleasing. I could just redirect straight from the ID route, but with the planned friends and groups, I will end up with URLS such as:

```
https://domain.com/en/community/id/:userid/friends
https://domain.com/en/community/users/:username/friends
https://domain.com/en/community/id/:userid/groups
https://domain.com/en/community/users/:username/groups
```

How can I always redirect from `/id/:userid` to `/users/:username` but keep the rest of the URL?

The first task is matching all URLs with `/id/:userid` to use the same route callback.

The second task is to replace the `/id/:userid` with `/users/:username`.

Can these two tasks be achieved with Regular Expressions?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out it was very simple to allow the user ID alias.

I can use an asterisk to capture all the other URLs, and then use a simple RegExp replace call to replace the ID with the Username.

```
app.get('/:lang/community/id/:id/*', function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    User.getByID(id, function(err, result, user){
        var url = req.url.replace(new RegExp('/id/'+id, 'g'), '/users/'+user.name);
        res.redirect(url);
    }
});
```

This is the best solution I could think of. I hope it helps other people.